# autowire DataSource to a class which extends JdbcDaoSupport

Tags: java, spring, datasource, autowired, spring-bean

I'm developing java,spring web application. I had some problems with adding DataSource to the DAO implement class which extends JdbcDaoSupport.

I searched through the internet and found similar solution.

DaoImpliment Class

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements UserDAO {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@PostConstruct
private void initialize() {
    setDataSource(dataSource);
}

public int getUserID(String userName) {
    //testing JDBC
    String sql = "select user_id from  users where username =" + "'" + userName + "'";
    List<UserDTO> userDTOs = new ArrayList<UserDTO>();

    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql);
    for (Map row : rows) {
        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setUserID((Integer) row.get("CUST_ID"));
        userDTOs.add(userDTO);
    }

    int userID = userDTOs.get(0).getUserID();

    return userID;
}
}
```

and my bean configaration.

```
<bean id="userDao" class="com.avers.dao.UserDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aversdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

but this gives me the error.
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

I think the error is in bean configuration.
I'm new to spring and someone please help.

Comment: is ur DataSource configuration defined in the xml config file?

Comment: yes. that was already there.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you `@Autowired` `DataSource` as well as provided as a reference property in the same `UserDAOImpl` class which is causing [NestedServletException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/NestedServletException.html). You can be avoid it in 2 ways:

1. Remove `@Autowired` from `DataSource` in your `UserDAOImpl` class as below:

   ```
   @Repository
   public class UserDAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements UserDAO {

   private DataSource dataSource;

   @PostConstruct
   private void initialize() {
     setDataSource(dataSource);
   }

   public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
       this.dataSource = dataSource;
   }

   public int getUserID(String userName) {
       //testing JDBC
       String sql = "select user_id from  users where username =" + "'" + userName + "'";
       List<UserDTO> userDTOs = new ArrayList<UserDTO>();

       List<Map<String, Object>> rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql);
       for (Map row : rows) {
           UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
           userDTO.setUserID((Integer) row.get("CUST_ID"));
           userDTOs.add(userDTO);
       }

       int userID = userDTOs.get(0).getUserID();

       return userID;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Or remove  `<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />` from your bean configuration file as below:

   ```
   <bean id="userDao" class="com.avers.dao.UserDAOImpl"/>
   <bean id="dataSource"
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

   <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aversdb"/>
   <property name="username" value="root"/>
   <property name="password" value=""/>
   </bean>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**@Autowired** annotation manages initialization instead of you. When an object that contains a field, that is @Autowired is created, all @Autowired fields are created.

That means, that you don't need initialization method below.

Please comment and tell me if this worked. More information can be found:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/